# How to update WP Silverlight ListBox bound to List<T>?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, data-binding, listbox, refresh

I have a classic ListBox control bound to a List in my Silverlight app for WP8. I need to update it after I have added some new items to the list. How to do that?

Please, don't suggest using ObservableCollection - I need to solve the problem for a List.

Comment: What Muhammad Saifullah said is normally the way to do it. But may I ask why do you insist on using a List? Or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is what an ObservableCollection was created for ... data-binding with minimal coding. If you don't want to use the correct data type then you need to do things the long way, as shown in Muhammad's answer.

Comment: @yasen, ObservableCollection may emit many notifications about list changes and theoretically cause bad performance. Besides, in some cases we simply cannot change the nature of the data class we'd like to visualize with ListBox.

Comment: You can always wrap your data in an OC unless you're using a control that simply does not support it. And changing the whole list is unlikely to have better performance - OC helps for that as well. The only thing that might be faster is to make (almost) everything yourself, so that it would be perfect for your situation. I would not recommend that, though.

Answer (score 1):

if you are not using MVVM design pattern than set ListBox ItemSource to null and set itemssource again with the new list.

```
listbox.ItemsSource = null;
listbox.ItemsSource = yourUpdatedList;
```

Model Class

```
 public class MyClass:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private List<Country> _countries = null;

    public const string CountriesPropertyName = "Countries";
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the Countries property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public List<Country> Countries
    {
        get
        {
            return _countries;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_countries == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _countries = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(CountriesPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

In your page.xaml.cs

```
var theModel =new MyModel();
theModel.Countries = yourcountryList;
```

the above code is not mvvm but it should work.

Comment: I know this trick, but is there another more elegant solution or a special dedicated method? For instance, I decompiled the ListBox/ItemsControl class, and internally it calls the statement `itemsControl.Items.UpdateItemsSourceList((IEnumerable)e.NewValue);` when the DependencyProperty ItemsSource is assigned.

Comment: I have had the same issue when re-assigning itemsSource to the listbox. It just does not updated on re-assigning.

the more better way is to use MVVM pattern. or using INotifyPropertyChanged interface on your class. I will update the post how you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which was designed to handle such tasks), you may build your own class and implement [INotifyCollectionChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) (that is was `ObservableCollection` does). Simple example with `Add` can look like this:

```
public class ObsList<T> : List<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    { if (CollectionChanged != null) CollectionChanged(this, e); }

    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
    }
}
```

Then your ListBox will be updated when you add item:

```
// your list
private ObsList<string> ItemsList = new ObsList<string>();

// somewhere in constructor:
myListBox.ItemsSource = ItemsList;

// and add item anywhere:
ItemsList.Add("Added item");
```